# Color for table in R studio console

Tags: r, knitr, kable

The out put of the following codes is odd. Someone can colorize the components in the following table ?

```
knitr::kable(

  data.frame(
    A=               c(1,2,3),
    B= crayon::cyan( c(4,5,6) ),
    C= crayon::cyan( c(7,8,9) ) 
            )
)
```

---

The output in the R cosole:

```
|  A|B           |C           |
|--:|:-----------|:-----------|
|  1|4 |7 |
|  2|5 |8 |
|  3|6 |9 |
```

where, the second and the third columns is colorized by cyan.

The odd means the second and the third columns not be aligned.

---

Other example:

```
knitr::kable(
    data.frame(
         a=c(1,crayon::red(2),3),
         b=c(TRUE,crayon::yellow(FALSE),TRUE)),  
    format = "pandoc"
)
```

I want to print using colors.

Comment: Can you explain more about what is odd? Also, is this code being executed within an R Markdown document or are you displaying the outputs in the console?

Comment: I am sorry I show the output in the above . I think your output is  normal. So,... This problem depends something ...